# Why does FINDSTR match and output nothing on being executed on several folders with a FOR loop?

Tags: cmd, foreach, findstr

I'm writing a batch script to iterate a `findstr` over files in different directories, but I get nothing. I'm sure that the string exists in all the files.

This is my script:

```
setlocal

rem Iterate each folder in the current directory.
for /d %%A in (*) do (

    rem Check if orca_input subfolder exist.
    if exist "\orca_input\%%~A" (

        rem Check if dft_opt.log files exist.
        if exist "\orca_input\%%~A\dft_opt.log" (

            rem Change working directory to where the files are temporarily.
            pushd "\orca_input\%%~A" && (

                rem Run the program.
                findstr /C:"Last Energy change" dft_opt.log > energychange.dat
                popd
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I'm not able to see errors.

**Edit:**

I tried this script according to the advice, but no file .dat is created.

```
setlocal

rem Iterate each folder in the current directory.
for /d %%A in (*) do (

    rem Check if dft_opt.log files exist.
    if exist "\orca_input\%%~A\dft_opt.log" (         

        rem Run the program.
        findstr /C:"Last Energy change" "\orca_input\%%~A\dft_opt.log" >"\orca_input\%%~A\energychange.dat"
    )
)
```

Comment: `"\orca_input\%%~A"`.  This will look for a folder `orca_input` at the **root** of the current drive.  Perhaps you want `"orca_input\%%~A"` to check for `orca_input` in the current directory?

Comment: Side note -- `if exist "\orca_input\%%~A"` is unnecessary because you have `if exist "\orca_input\%%~A\dft_opt.log"`

Comment: Side note #2 -- my personal preference is to avoid `pushd` and `popd`.  Instead you could `findstr /C:"Last Energy change" "\orca_input\%%~A\dft_opt.log" >"\orca_input\%%~A\energychange.dat"`

Comment: I have some folders in the "orca_input" folder, so I thought I need to go in one of the folder, do findstr, return to "orca_input" and iterate to another folder.

Comment: What is your folder structure?

Comment: What does `dir \orca_input` return?

Comment: It returns something like "file not found" (it's in my mothertongue). If I do `dir /b` it returns me the folders.

Comment: What does `dir .\orca_input` return?  From the directory you're interested in.

Comment: If I stay in one of the subfolders and run `dir .\orca_input` I got the same return: "file not found"

Comment: Where is the directory `orca_input` located?  It doesn't seem to be at the root, and it doesn't seem to exist in the current directory . . .

Comment: C:\Users\MiniHp\Documents\Università\Orca_input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
setlocal

rem Iterate each folder in the current directory.
for /d %%A in (*) do (
   rem Check if dft_opt.log file exists.
   if exist "orca_input\%%~A\dft_opt.log" (
      findstr /C:"Last Energy change" "orca_input\%%~A\dft_opt.log">"orca_input\%%~A\energychange.dat"
   )
)
```

I feel like we need to get the folder structure figure out.

Another alternative:

```
setlocal

rem Iterate each folder in the current directory.
for /d %%A in (*) do (
   rem Check if dft_opt.log file exists.
   if exist "%%~A\orca_input\dft_opt.log" (
      findstr /C:"Last Energy change" "%%~A\orca_input\dft_opt.log">"%%~A\orca_input\energychange.dat"
   )
)
```

3rd try:

```
setlocal

rem Iterate each folder in the current directory.
for /d %%A in (*) do (
   rem Check if dft_opt.log file exists.
   if exist "%%~A\dft_opt.log" (
      findstr /C:"Last Energy change" "%%~A\dft_opt.log">"%%~A\energychange.dat"
   )
)
```

Comment: Your original script was looking for `c:\orca_input\eachfoldername\dft_opt.log`.  But `orca_input` is not at the root of `c:\`.  Thus the location of the folders was wrong.  Your script was looking in the wrong place for what it wanted.  That's why nothing was returned.  We have to know *where* things are (your folder structure, or your directory tree) so we can properly reference them.

Comment: Now we know where `orca_input` is.  Give me an example directory of where one of the `dft_opt.log` files is.  And then tell me what folder you are running this script from.

Comment: I wrote the structure in a comment above. Thought that using the (*) it would look in the current folder I was...

Comment: An example is "formic". I'm running it from "orca_input"

Comment: So that means `C:\Users\MiniHp\Documents\Università\Orca_input\Formic\dft_opt.log` exists?  That's my 3rd script when run from `C:\Users\MiniHp\Documents\Università\Orca_input`.

Comment: Ok now I got the files. Thank you very much. Was the problem repeating "orca_input"?

Comment: There were 2 problems.  The first was using a leading backslash \.  That went to the root of `c:` instead of the current directory.  The second problem was repeating "orca_input".  Without the leading backslash you still would have been wrong by trying to find `C:\Users\MiniHp\Documents\Università\Orca_input\Orca_input\Formic\dft_opt.log` -- looking for an "Orca_input" folder nested inside the "Orca_input" folder.

Comment: I see. Thank you.